# How to create a custom windows metro style icon or tile?

Tags: icons, microsoft-metro, customization, startmenu

We are a software developer and our software installer creates start menu shortcuts. The shortcuts look great except in windows 10, primarily because our icon is blue and the metro styling creates a blue background.

Thus, after research I've determined we need a custom metro styled icon file. Unfortunately searches turn up zero on this; everything points me to metro studio, but this doesn't work for custom icons only, it only allows customization of existing icons from Microsoft.

Any help is appreciated. A walk thru would be ideal.

Comment: I think this is called *tiles* in Windows 10.

Comment: Really talking about the start menu icon under programs... but making something that works with tiles too wouldn't hurt, bonus points.

Comment: ah sorry now I see